# Rear wheel clicking

Tags: clicking

Jeep patriot rear area brakes when driving there is a very noticeable clicking sound. Once I press down on brake pedal it stops even when vehicle continues to slow down. Once I release brake pedal the clicking returns. Can you provide a possible reason for the clicking.  Thanks

Comment: Is it a loud sharp clicking or a faint noticable clicking, I had that issue once for 3 years but I never did anything about it because it was only when i heard it with my windows down, bad I know :) when I decided to change my brakes I realized that the back of the disk brakes had two brake shoes which had broke loose and were riding on the drum so when I went slow enough you could hear them separating and clapping like it was a relay with a time delay lol but when I pressed on the brakes the sound went away, does your parking brake work ?

Comment: You might want to reword this slightly, since “press down” and “depress” mean exactly the same thing.  You might want to use the word “release” instead of “depress”.

Comment: Moto it is a loud sharp clicking, once I release the brakes the sound returns

Comment: Do you have the front wheel drive patriot or the 4 wheel drive ?

Comment: 4 wheel drive patriot

Comment: Emergency brake is not working